# performing an segue doesn't works

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, segue

I want to the app to segue if the codes matches with the defined code inside .
So if I enter the code in the textfield nothing happens .
Do any of you maybe have some solutions for me ?

that is what I've got so far in the .m file of the ViewController

```
    @interface mainViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *zahlencode;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *done;
@property NSMutableArray *codes;


@end

@implementation mainViewController
- (void)loadInitialData {
    Code *item1 = [[Code alloc] init];
    item1.Code = @"1";
    [self.codes addObject:item1];
}
int a,b,c,zz;
a=1;
b=2;
c=3;

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (sender != self.done)
        return;
    if (self.zahlencode.text.length > 0)
    {
        zz =[self.zahlencode.text intValue];
        if(zz == a)
        {

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"1"];        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `prepareForSegue:sender:` runs after `performSegueWithIdentifier:`.

Comment: But I only want to segue if the code is right . Is this working after that too ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a segue in your storyboard with the identifier "1"?
If not then add it to the segue.

Does your code reach the *performSegueWithIdentifier* (did you do a *NSLog()* to ensure that the code is executed)?

**UPDATE:**

You should try this:

Add an action from your UIButton and inside that you write the code to perform the segue.
(Add the action from the storyboard, like an outlet)

```
- (void) ButtonPressed: (id) sender
{
    if (sender != self.done)
        return;
    if (self.zahlencode.text.length > 0)
    {
        zz =[self.zahlencode.text intValue];
        if(zz == a)
        {

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"1" sender:self];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do have a segue with the identifier 1. but not the NSlog thing cuz i don't really know how that works

Comment: Here a little example that you could use to see if the performSegueWithIdentifier is executed:  `NSLog(@"DONE");` Just add it right before or after the performSegueWithIdentifier

Comment: The error at the performSegueWithIdentifier is still there (No visible @interface for 'mainViewController' declares the selector 'performSegueWithIdentifier:')

Comment: I entered the "1" int he textfield and pressed done then this error appears and the app crashed : `[mainViewController done:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d2c610
2014-03-18 10:15:19.983 AbteiRD[6955:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[mainViewController done:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d2c610' `

Comment: Could you switch to the Breakpoint Navigator and add Exeption Breakpoint and then try it again, this way it should be easier to get where the problem is.

Comment: `- (IBAction)done:(UIButton *)sender {
    - (void) ButtonPressed: (id) sender
    {
        if (sender != self.done)
            return;
        if (self.zahlencode.text.length > 0)
        {
            zz =[self.zahlencode.text intValue];
            if(zz == a)
            {
                
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"1" sender:self];
            }
        }
    }}
` Is that right ? And where shall i do the breakpoints ? Sorry I´m quite new with that

Comment: Look at this site: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/about_breakpoint_navigator.html) press the + button and add an Exception Breakpoint

Comment: Now there is standing "undeclared identifier ButtonPressed" If I do that inside of the IBAction

Comment: Did you create an action named "ButtonPressed" via the storyboard, linked to the button?